# Smart View Error: "The request timed out. Contact your administrator to increase netRetrycount and netRetryInterval"

Tags: hyperion, essbase

While running a query via smartview on Excel its throwing below error.
"The request timed out. Contact your administrator to increase netRetrycount and netRetryInterval" or "to extend your Windows Internet Explorer time out settings (ReceiveTimeout, KeepAliveTimeout, and ServerInfoTimeout)"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below solution fixed the issue for me.

1. Open Windows Registry Editor: Start -> Run -> type regedit
   Before making any changes backup Windows Registry using "Export" option.
2. Locate the following section:

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings]

3. Create the following new DWORD keys with decimal values as shown in the picture :

> ReceiveTimeout=480000
>
> KeepAliveTimeout=180000
>
> ServerInfoTimeout=180000

In this example, the ReceiveTimeout setting is 8 minutes.  The KeepAliveTimeout and ServerInfoTimeout settings are 3 minutes.  Set these values high enough to fulfill large requests.

4. Restart the machine for the new settings to take effect.
   [image]

Reference
https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=317768279645392&id=972912.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=1xztby476_397